# Creating layout directives in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Folks,

I am trying to align a bunch of rows under a custom header.

The header goes something like this :

```
$scope.header =  [ 
 { column:'name',  width: '80'},
{ column:'city', width: '80'},
{column:'hobby',  width: '200'}
{column:'age',  width: '80'}
];
```

The data goes something like this :

```
$scope.students = [ 
{
'city: 'new york',
'name':'James hans',
'age': '35'
},
{
'name':'Superman'
'city: 'los angeles',
'hobby': 'crime fighter',
'age':'30'
},
{
'name':'Spiderman'
'city: 'unknown',
},
];
```

The output should look like:

```
Name                    City                 Hobby                  Age
james hans        new York                    -                     35
Superman          los angeles            crime fighter              30
Spiderman         unkown                      -                     -
```

At the end of the day i am looking to create a directive that can be used like below.

```
<dir    column-headers="header" column-body="students"    custom-layout /> 
</dir>
```

Does anyone know how i can achieve this ?

Plnkr: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/TG6aCEu2TgPq28Jcj0nM

Comment: Is there a reason you need a directive for this?

Comment: What does your current `directive` look like?  What have you tried?  Please do not just link to a Plnkr with "now what?" in your `directive` and ask us to do the work.

Comment: So far the progress is slow. I have upated the pnkr and have managed to layout the header row just fine. The task now is to print out all rows below it.  updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/TG6aCEu2TgPq28Jcj0nM

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option to dynamically load template by templateUrl.

Basically, templateUrl in directive can be a function of form `function(elem, attr)`. From there you can read the value of the attr and set the template accordingly.

See example here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1039#issuecomment-30939037

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue finally. 
You can see from the plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TG6aCEu2TgPq28Jcj0nM